# Rails 5: DEPRECATION WARNING: You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `exists?`. ..I have no idea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok....I have a form in a modal that I am trying to submit. I do not understand the Warning / error I am getting that is keeping the POST from taking place.  What am I missing?

Here is the Deprication Warning that is drivin me nuts

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `exists?`. Please pass the id of the object by calling `.id`. (called from block in create at /home/fonso/back-experiment/app/controllers/assignments_controller.rb:35)
```

Note that there is no "exists?" on line 35 (see below).
This is the controller action with line 35 marked

```
  # POST /assignments or /assignments.json
  def create
    @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)

    # error wants contact.id not contact_id ???

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save  #<-------------------LINE 35
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

If I stop it with Pry to see the object getting passed I see...
Pry console output

```
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:4000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started POST "/assignments" for 22.222.22.222 at 2021-11-05 20:34:11 -0700
Cannot render console from 22.222.22.222! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by AssignmentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "volunteer_task_type_id"=>"41", "roster_id"=>"7", "program_id"=>"9", "set_description"=>["fonso nov5 test"], "set_date"=>["2021-01-05"], "assignment"=>{"start_time(1i)"=>"2021", "start_time(2i)"=>"11", "start_time(3i)"=>"6", "start_time(4i)"=>"08", "start_time(5i)"=>"00", "end_time(1i)"=>"2021", "end_time(2i)"=>"11", "end_time(3i)"=>"6", "end_time(4i)"=>"09", "end_time(5i)"=>"00", "notes"=>"nov5", "contact_id"=>"166574", "closed"=>"1", "lock_version"=>"0"}, "contact_element_prefix"=>"contact", "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Contact Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 166574], ["LIMIT", 1]]

From: /home/fonso/back-experiment/app/controllers/assignments_controller.rb @ line 31 in AssignmentsController#create:

    26:   end
    27: 
    28:   # POST /assignments or /assignments.json
    29:   def create
    30:     @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
 => 31:     binding.pry
    32:     # error wants contact.id not contact_id ???
    33:     # try the create_shift code here??
    34:     # NOTE: comment original out 4 now <--- WHY? this saves add_shift now
    35: 
    36:     respond_to do |format|
pry(#<AssignmentsController>)> @assignment
=> #<Assignment:0x00007f641862e610
 id: nil,
 volunteer_shift_id: nil,
 contact_id: 166574,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 attendance_type_id: nil,
 notes: "nov5",
 call_status_type_id: nil,
 closed: true,
 lock_version: 0,
 color: nil,
 start_time: Sat, 06 Nov 2021 08:00:00 UTC +00:00,
 end_time: Sat, 06 Nov 2021 09:00:00 UTC +00:00>
pry(#<AssignmentsController>)>
```

What is this thing asking me for? What am I missing?

If the outcome is that no data is saved to the database and instead there is a ROLLBACK. Then from my perspective something is broken and this is an "error". Or rather and "error" has occurred in that the outcome is not what is desired.

```
Processing by AssignmentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "volunteer_task_type_id"=>"41", "roster_id"=>"7", "program_id"=>"9", "set_description"=>["fonso nov5 test"], "set_date"=>["2021-01-05"], "assignment"=>{"start_time(1i)"=>"2021", "start_time(2i)"=>"11", "start_time(3i)"=>"6", "start_time(4i)"=>"08", "start_time(5i)"=>"00", "end_time(1i)"=>"2021", "end_time(2i)"=>"11", "end_time(3i)"=>"6", "end_time(4i)"=>"09", "end_time(5i)"=>"00", "notes"=>"nov5", "contact_id"=>"166574", "closed"=>"1", "lock_version"=>"0"}, "contact_element_prefix"=>"contact", "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Contact Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 166574], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `exists?`. Please pass the id of the object by calling `.id`. (called from block in create at /home/fonso/back-experiment/app/controllers/assignments_controller.rb:35)
  Contact Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 166574], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering assignments/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  VolunteerTaskType Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "volunteer_task_types".* FROM "volunteer_task_types" WHERE "volunteer_task_types"."instantiable" = $1 AND ((effective_on IS NULL OR effective_on <= '2021-11-05') AND (ineffective_on IS NULL OR ineffective_on > '2021-11-05'))  [["instantiable", "t"]]
  Roster Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "rosters".* FROM "rosters"
```

Execution STOPS and nothing is posted to my database.

Comment: A warning is not an error, it shouldn't prevent your code to work. Show the actual error, the complete error, not just a comment saying there's an error. Show the assignment_params method, show your model and the associations. try `save!` to see the error better.

Comment: @arieljuod the error is now shown. The problem is with data not code and trying to create a duplicate record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Contact Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 166574], ["LIMIT", 1]]

This is telling you that your contact already exists so if you want that code to work then create a contact that does not already exist or change your models code that does this check or the database schema if that is where you have a unique property set, you have NO error in your code, the warning is just a deprecation warning not an error.
You seem to be accessing a record that already exists so maybe you are wanting to update rather than create? this may be a logic error rather than a coding error but only you know what it is you are trying to do

Comment: @thefonso hope it helps at least point you in the right direction so that you can figure out what you need to do from here, feel free to comment on my answer if you need more info

Comment: I hope I asked this question properly... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861586/rails5-how-to-change-my-models-code-that-does-this-check  much appreciation if you see anything that could help (once more)