# Rails5: How to change my models code that does this check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a form I'm trying to submit that keeps getting jammed with a Deprecation Warning that I have posted on this SO question...

[Rails 5: DEPRECATION WARNING: You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `exists?`. ..I have no idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861364/rails-5-deprecation-warning-you-are-passing-an-instance-of-activerecordbase#69861468)

Someone was kind enough to point me in the general direction of what to do. Now I'm trying to figure out how or where the contact needs a .id attached to it. Here is my controller code associated with the problem followed by two models, one for the assignments and one for the contact.

So the ask is. where/what change must I make to resolve this Deprecation Warning ?(originally posted on the SO link above)

```
Processing by AssignmentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "volunteer_task_type_id"=>"41", "roster_id"=>"7", "program_id"=>"9", "set_description"=>["fonso nov5 test"], "set_date"=>["2021-01-05"], "assignment"=>{"start_time(1i)"=>"2021", "start_time(2i)"=>"11", "start_time(3i)"=>"6", "start_time(4i)"=>"08", "start_time(5i)"=>"00", "end_time(1i)"=>"2021", "end_time(2i)"=>"11", "end_time(3i)"=>"6", "end_time(4i)"=>"09", "end_time(5i)"=>"00", "notes"=>"nov5", "contact_id"=>"166574", "closed"=>"1", "lock_version"=>"0"}, "contact_element_prefix"=>"contact", "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Contact Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 166574], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `exists?`. Please pass the id of the object by calling `.id`. (called from block in create at /home/fonso/back-experiment/app/controllers/assignments_controller.rb:35)
  Contact Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 166574], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering assignments/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  VolunteerTaskType Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "volunteer_task_types".* FROM "volunteer_task_types" WHERE "volunteer_task_types"."instantiable" = $1 AND ((effective_on IS NULL OR effective_on <= '2021-11-05') AND (ineffective_on IS NULL OR ineffective_on > '2021-11-05'))  [["instantiable", "t"]]
  Roster Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "rosters".* FROM "rosters"
```

assignments controller

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #TODO refactor this line to be very specific

  # GET /assignments or /assignments.json
  def index
    # @assignments = Assignment.limit(20)
    # @assignments = Assignment.where(start: params[:start]..params[:end])
    @assignments = Assignment.date_range(params[:start]..params[:end])

  end

  # GET /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /assignments/new
  def new
    @assignment = Assignment.new
    @my_url = {:action => "create", :id => params[:id]}
  end

  # GET /assignments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /assignments or /assignments.json
  def create
    @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)

    # error wants contact.id not contact_id ???

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save  <-------THIS IS LINE 35
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def update
    @assignment.update(assignment_params)
  end

  # DELETE /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def destroy
    @assignment.destroy
    # NOTE: comment original out 4 now
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html { redirect_to assignments_url, notice: "Assignment was successfully destroyed." }
    #   format.json { head :no_content }
    # end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_assignment
      @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def assignment_params
      params.require(:assignment).permit(:title,:redirect_to, :set_date, :date_range, :volunteer_shift_id, :contact_id, :start_time, :end_time, :start, :end, :attendance_type_id, :notes, :call_status_type_id, :closed, :lock_version, :color)
    end
end
```

assignment Model

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :volunteer_shift
  has_one :volunteer_task_type, :through => :volunteer_shift, :source => :volunteer_task_type
  belongs_to :contact
  validates_presence_of :volunteer_shift
  validates_associated :volunteer_shift
  belongs_to :attendance_type
  belongs_to :call_status_type
  validates_presence_of :set_date, :if => :volshift_stuck
  validates_existence_of :contact, :allow_nil => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_shift

  #fixme: Nodule::DelegationError -
  # This error appears when trying to show the "Add New Assignment" model on the /assignments view
  delegate :set_date, :set_date=, :to => :volunteer_shift
  delegate :set_description, :set_description=, :to => :volunteer_shift

  scope :date_range, lambda { |range|
    joins(volunteer_shift: :volunteer_event)
        .where(volunteer_shifts: { volunteer_events: { date: range } })
  }
  scope :is_after_today, lambda {||
    { :conditions => ['(SELECT date FROM volunteer_events WHERE id = (SELECT volunteer_event_id FROM volunteer_shifts WHERE id = assignments.volunteer_shift_id)) > ?', Date.today] }
  }
  scope :on_or_after_today, lambda {||
    { :conditions => ['(SELECT date FROM volunteer_events WHERE id = (SELECT volunteer_event_id FROM volunteer_shifts WHERE id = assignments.volunteer_shift_id)) >= ?', Date.today] }
  }
  scope :not_cancelled, -> { where('(attendance_type_id IS NULL OR attendance_type_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM attendance_types WHERE cancelled = \'t\'))')}
  scope :roster_is_limited_by_program, -> {where("roster_id IN (SELECT id FROM rosters WHERE limit_shift_signup_by_program = 't')").joins(:volunteer_shift)}

  attr_accessor :attendance_type_id



  #fixme: fix all red dots on this page
  def real_programs
    return [] unless self.volunteer_shift&.roster
    return [] unless self.volunteer_shift.roster.limit_shift_signup_by_program
    self.volunteer_shift.roster.skeds.select{|x| x.category_type == "Program"}.map{|x| x.name}
  end

# TODO: find all time_range_s methods and either pull out to DRY or give unique names
  def time_range_s
    return "" unless start_time and end_time
    (start_time.strftime("%I:%M") + ' - ' + end_time.strftime("%I:%M")).gsub( ':00', '' ).gsub( ' 0', ' ').gsub( ' - ', '-' ).gsub(/^0/, "")
  end

  def description
    self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.date.strftime("%D") + " " + self.time_range_s + " " + self.slot_type_desc
  end

  def roster_title
    self.volunteer_shift.roster.name
  end

  #fixme: date / set_date is fracked since old code was ported over
   def date
     volunteer_shift.date
   end

  #full calendar uses this method name....see the assignment.json.jbuilder
  def event_date
    self.date
  end

  def slot_type_desc
    b = (self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_task_type_id.nil? ? self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.description : self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_task_type.description)
    b = b + " (#{self.volunteer_shift.description})" if self.volunteer_shift.description and self.volunteer_shift.description.length > 0
    b
  end

  def display_name
    ((!(self.volunteer_shift.description.nil? or self.volunteer_shift.description.blank?)) ? self.volunteer_shift.description + ": " : "") + self.contact_display
  end

  def cancelled?
    (self.attendance_type&.cancelled)
  end

  def attended?
    (self.attendance_type and !self.attendance_type.cancelled)
  end

  def contact_display
    if self.closed
      "(closed)"
    elsif contact_id.nil?
      return "(available)"
    else
      self.contact.display_name + "(#{self.voltask_count})"
    end
  end

  def <=>(other)
    self.date <=> other.date
  end

  def contact_id=(new_val)
    self.write_attribute(:contact_id, new_val)
    self.contact = Contact.find_by_id(new_val.to_i)
  end

  def contact_id_and_by_today
    # Unless the contact id is empty, or the event date is after today.
    !(contact_id.nil? || self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.date > Date.today)
  end

  def voltask_count
    self.contact_volunteer_task_type_count ? self.contact_volunteer_task_type_count.attributes["count"] : 0
  end

  before_validation :set_values_if_stuck
  def set_values_if_stuck
    return unless volshift_stuck
    volunteer_shift.set_values_if_stuck(self)
  end

  after_destroy { |record| if record.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment; record.volunteer_shift.destroy; else VolunteerShift.find_by_id(record.volunteer_shift_id).fill_in_available; end}
  after_save {|record| if record.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment; record.volunteer_shift.save; end}
  after_save { |record| VolunteerShift.find_by_id(record.volunteer_shift_id).fill_in_available }

  # def volunteer_shift_attributes=(attrs) #fixme: why is this not getting called on volunteer_events/create_shift?
  #   self.volunteer_shift.attributes=(attrs) # just pass it up
  # end

#fixme: where is stuck_to_assignment ??? WTF?
  def volshift_stuck
    self.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment
  end

  def first_time_in_area?
    if self.contact and self.volunteer_shift and self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_task_type
      !ContactVolunteerTaskTypeCount.has_volunteered?(self.contact_id, self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_task_type_id)
    else
      false
    end #  and self.contact_id_changed? moved outside because we use update_attributes
  end

#for fullcalendar
  def all_day_event?
    self.start_time == self.start_time.midnight && self.end_time == self.end_time.midnight ? true : false
  end
end
```

Contact model

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract

  has_many :assignments

  has_many :contact_types_contacts
  has_many :contact_types, :through => :contact_types_contacts
  has_many :contact_methods
  has_many :contact_method_types, :through => :contact_methods

  has_many :volunteer_tasks, -> {order 'date_performed DESC'}
  has_many :volunteer_task_types, :through => :volunteer_tasks
  has_many :builder_tasks
  has_many :disciplinary_actions, :autosave => true



  # TODO: do these two even work?
  def future_shifts
    self.assignments.on_or_after_today.not_cancelled.sort{|a,b| t = a.date <=> b.date; t == 0 ? a.start_time <=> b.start_time : t}
  end
  def scheduled_shifts
    a = future_shifts
    more = false
    if a.length > 5
      a = a[0,5]
      more = true
    end
    a = a.map{|x| x.description}
    a << "More.." if more # FIXME: this needs to be a link
    a.join("<br/>")
  end

  def is_organization?
    self.is_organization
  end

  def is_person?
    ! self.is_organization?
  end

  def mailing_list_email
    list = ContactMethodType.email_types_ordered.map{|x| x.id}
    list = list.reverse if self.is_organization?
    result = self.contact_methods.select{|x| x.ok}.select{|x| list.include?(x.contact_method_type_id)}.sort{|a,b| r = (list.index(a.contact_method_type_id) <=> list.index(b.contact_method_type_id)); r == 0 ? ((b.updated_at || b.created_at) <=> (a.updated_at || a.created_at)) : r}.first
    result ? result.value : nil
  end

  # used to find when a volunteer is scheduled for more than 2 shifts
  def schedule_counts
    h = {}
    return h if self.is_organization? # organizations may schedule as much as they like
    assns = self.assignments.is_after_today.roster_is_limited_by_program.not_cancelled
    assns.each do |a|
      progs = a.real_programs
      progs.each do |p|
        h[p] ||= 0
        h[p] += 1
      end
    end
    h
  end

  def date_of_last_adoption
    last_adoption = Disbursement.where("(disbursement_type_id = ? OR disbursement_type_id = ?) AND contact_id = ?", DisbursementType.find_by_name("adoption").id, DisbursementType.find_by_name("build").id, id).order("disbursed_at DESC").first
    if last_adoption
      return Date.parse(last_adoption.disbursed_at.to_s)
    else
      return nil
    end
  end

  def spec_sheets_since_last_adoption(action_name)
    BuilderTask.all.where("contact_id = ? AND builder_tasks.created_at > ? AND cashier_signed_off_by IS NOT NULL AND action_id = ?", self.id, date_of_last_adoption || Date.parse("2000-01-01"), Action.find_by_name(action_name).id)
  end

  def phone_numbers
    a = []
    contact_methods.map {|x|
      a << x.value if (x.contact_method_type.description =~ /phone|fax/ and !(x.contact_method_type.description =~ /emergency/) and x.ok == true) # TODO: does ruby support negative lookbehinds?
    }
    a
  end

  def phone_number
    phone_numbers.first
  end

  def has_areas_disciplined_from?
    self.areas_disciplined_from.length > 0
  end
  def areas_disciplined_from
    self.disciplinary_actions.not_disabled.map(&:disciplinary_action_areas).flatten.uniq.sort_by(&:name)
  end

  def find_volunteer_tasks(cutoff = nil, klass = VolunteerTask, contact_id_type = "", date_field = "date_performed", max = nil)
    # if it's named volunteer_tasks it breaks everything
    contact_id_type = contact_id_type + "_" if contact_id_type.length > 0
    if max and cutoff
      conditions = [ "#{contact_id_type}contact_id = ? AND #{date_field} > ? AND #{date_field} < ?", id, cutoff, max ]
    elsif cutoff
      conditions = [ "#{contact_id_type}contact_id = ? AND #{date_field} > ?", id, cutoff ]
    elsif max
      conditions = [ "#{contact_id_type}contact_id = ? AND #{date_field} < ?", id, max ]
    else
      conditions = [ "#{contact_id_type}contact_id = ?", id ]
    end
    klass.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
  end
  def last_ninety_days_of_volunteer_tasks
    find_volunteer_tasks(Date.today - Default['days_for_discount'].to_f)
  end
  def last_ninety_days_of_effective_hours
    last_ninety_days_of_volunteer_tasks.inject(0.0) {|tot,task|
      tot + task.duration
    }
  end
  def has_worker?
    ! self.worker.nil? && worker.effective_now?
  end
  def default_discount_schedule
    if self.has_worker?
      return "staff"
    elsif last_ninety_days_of_effective_hours >= Default['hours_for_discount'].to_f
      return "volunteer"
    else
      return "no_discount"
    end
  end

  def sorted_contact_methods
    ContactMethodType.sort_methods(contact_methods)
  end

  def display_name
    if is_person?
      if(self.first_name || self.middle_name || self.surname)
        "%s %s %s" % [self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.surname]
      else
        '(person without name)'
      end
    else
      if self.organization && ! self.organization.empty?
        self.organization
      else
        '(organization without name)'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Side note: much of this code is inherited and I'm trying to port / update it to Rails 5 (reasons).

UPDATE: adding view files

Here is the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_event">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="col-sm-12 left ">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Assignment - _new.html.erb</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= @my_url.inspect %>
    
      <%= render 'assignments/form', assignment: @assignment %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the _form.html.erb called by the modal

```
<%= form_for @assignment, :url => @my_url, remote: true do |f| %>

  <div class="">
    <div class="modal-body  d-flex">
      <div class="col-sm-8 border-right">
        <section id="location-date-time-notes" class="flex">
          <% if @assignment.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@assignment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this assignment from being saved:</h2>
              <ul>
                <% @assignment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <!--    set variable values for use later-->
          <%# is_r = false %>
<!--this will never exist in this case-->
          <%# shift = is_r ? f.object.volunteer_shift : f.object.volunteer_default_shift %>
          <%# event = is_r ? shift.volunteer_event : shift.volunteer_default_event %>
          <%# resources = is_r ? event.resources_volunteer_events : event.resources_volunteer_default_events %>
          <%#= binding.pry %>
          <%# assigns = is_r ? shift.assignments : shift.default_assignments %>
          <%# if !is_r; assigns = assigns.select{|x| x.slot_number == f.object.slot_number}; end %>
          <%# my_date = is_r ? shift.date : event.weekday.name %>
          <!--VOLUNTEER SHIFT-->
          <!--TODO: make this a partial-->
          <div class="name large flex-row">
            <%= f.label :volunteer_shift %>
          </div>
          <div id="volunteer_shift" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 p-2">
              <div id="volunteer_shift" class="text-right">
                <!-- if class is assignment show volunteer shift else show default shift -->

                <%#= f.label :volunteer_shift %>

                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :volunteer_task_type_id %>
                  <%= select_tag 'volunteer_task_type_id', options_from_collection_for_select([VolunteerTaskType.new(:description => ""),  VolunteerTaskType.instantiables.effective_on(Date.today)].flatten, "id", "description")  %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :roster_id %>
                  <%= select_tag 'roster_id', options_from_collection_for_select([Roster.new(:name => ""), Roster.all].flatten, "id", "name") %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :program_id %>
                  <%= select_tag 'program_id', options_from_collection_for_select([Program.new(:name => ""), Program.where(:volunteer => true)].flatten, "id", "name")%>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :set_description %>
                  <%= text_field(:set_description, nil) %>
                </div>
       
                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :set_date, "Date" %> <
                  <%= text_field(:set_date, nil) %> 
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--TODO: Volunteer Shift end -->
          <%#= f.hidden_field :redirect_to, :value => @referer %>

          <div id="time-row" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <label for="assignment_time" class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Time:
            </label>
            <div class="col- p-2">
              <div class="myStartTime"  id="start_time_<%= assignment.id %>">
                <%= f.time_select :start_time %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col- p-2"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <div class="myEndTime"  id="end_time_<%= assignment.id %>">
                <%= f.time_select :end_time %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <label for="assignment_notes" class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Notes:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 p-2">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <span> Notes only get saved if a contact is assigned the shift, and get removed when the contact is removed from the shift.</span>
                <div class="">
                  <%= f.label :notes %>
                  <%= f.text_area :notes %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">

        <!-- Contact Section-->
        <div id="contact_section">
          <% if @assigned_contacts &&  @assigned_contacts.length > 0 %>
            <h2>Previously Assigned Contacts</h2>
            <% @assigned_contacts.each do |c| %>
              <%= label_tag "assigned_contacts[#{c.id}]", "Are you sure you want to remove the currently scheduled volunteer, #{c.display_name} (##{c.id}), from the assignment(s)?" %>
              <%= check_box_tag "assigned_contacts[#{c.id}]", "replace", @replaced_contacts.include?(c.id) %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <input id="contact_element_prefix" name="contact_element_prefix" type="hidden" value="contact">
          <div class="name large flex-row">
            <%= f.label :contact_id %><%= f.text_field :contact_id %>
          </div>

          <div id="display-contact" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <% if f.object.contact_id %>
              <%= render partial: 'contacts/display', locals: {contact:f.object.contact} %>
            <% else %>
              <%#= link_to 'Show Contact', contact_path(f.object.contact_id),  remote: true %>
            <% end %>
          </div>

          <!--    FIXME: replace this logic stack with AJAX-->
          <%#= contact_field("@obj", "contact_id",
        :locals => {:options => {
        :object_name => f.object_name.to_s,
        :field_name => 'contact_id',
        :on_display => 'display_disciplinary_notes(); display_contact_notes();'
        }}
                      ) %>
          <%= f.label :closed, "Is this slot closed?" %>
          <%= f.check_box :closed %>

          <!--Contact Section END-->

          <!--Attendance / Call Status End-->
          <% if f.object.id && f.object.contact_id %>
            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="col-25"><label for="assignment_attendance_type_id">Attendance:</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><%= select(f.object_name,
                                             "attendance_type_id",
                                             AttendanceType.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },
                                             :include_blank => true) %></div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="col-25"><label for="assignment_call_status_type_id">Call status:</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><%= select(f.object_name,
                                             "call_status_type_id",
                                             ([["not called yet", ""]] + CallStatusType.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }),
                                             :include_blank => false) %></div>

            </div>
          <% end %>
          <!-- Attendance / Call Status End-->

          <!-- LOCK VERSION-->
          <div class="flex-row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <%= f.label :lock_version %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <%= f.number_field :lock_version %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- LOCK end-->
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="edit_icons d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <!--            <a href="/assignments/edit/<%#= skedj.current.id %>" title="split"><i class="fa fa-share-alt-square fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Split</a>-->
          <!--            <a href="/assignments/copy/<%#= skedj.current.id %>" title="copy"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copy</a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <%#= link_to '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit'.html_safe, edit_assignment_path,  remote: true%>
          <!--            <a href="#" onclick="reassign(<%#= skedj.current.id %>); return false;" title="reassign"> <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reassign</a>-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= f.submit "Submit" %></button>
        <!--              <input id="assignment_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update">-->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

<% end %>
```

_display.html.erb

```
<% @contact = contact %>


<div class="FONSO contact_display">
  <div class="name large"><%= h @contact.display_name %></div>
  <br />

  <div class="id">
    <%= ( @contact.contact_types.map {|c_t|
      h(c_t.description)
    }.sort << (@contact.is_organization ? 'organization' : 'person')
        ).join(', ') %>
    (id: <%= @contact.id %>, created: <%= @contact.created_at.nil? ? "unknown" : @contact.created_at.to_date %>
    <%#= ", login: #{h @contact.user.login}" if @contact.user %>)
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="address"><%= h @contact.address %><br />
    <%= h @contact.city %>, <%= h @contact.state_or_province %> <%= h @contact.postal_code %>
  </div>
  <br />
<!--TODO: why this not show up?-->
  <div class="contact_methods">
    <span>CONTACT METHODS:</span><br />
    <% for method in @contact.sorted_contact_methods %>
      <%= h method.display %><br />
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <br />
  <% if @contact.has_areas_disciplined_from? or (@contact.notes && @contact.notes != '') %>
    <div class="contact_comments">
      <% if @contact.has_areas_disciplined_from? %>
        Cannot volunteer in these areas (check with a staff member for assistance):<br />
        <ul>
          <% @contact.areas_disciplined_from.map(&:name).each do |d| %>
            <li><%= d %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
      <% if @contact.notes && @contact.notes != '' %>
        <span>Notes:</span><br/>
        <%= h(@contact.notes).gsub(/\n/, "") %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% checked_since = @contact.spec_sheets_since_last_adoption("checker").length %>
  <% built_since = @contact.spec_sheets_since_last_adoption("builder").length %>

  <% if (checked_since + built_since) > 0 %>
    <div>
      Computers QAed since last adoption: <%= checked_since %><br/>
      Computers Built since last adoption: <%= built_since %><br/>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <% attends = @contact.assignments.select{|x| x.attended? and x.volunteer_shift.class_credit}.map{|x| x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event}.map{|x| x.description + " on " + x.date.strftime("%D")}.join(", ") %>
  <% if !attends.blank? %>
    Attended Classes:<br />
    <%= attends %><br />
  <% end %>

<!--ASSOCIATIONS BLOCK-->
  <div class="associations">
  <% if coveredness_enabled %>
    <%=
      "Fully Covered: " +
          case @contact.fully_covered
          when nil then "UNKNOWN"
          when true then "Yes"
          when false then "No"
          end
    %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: What is line 35 in your controller?

Comment: Updated: pointed out line 35 that lives inside the create action

Comment: You might well find running a console and updating/creating a record manually helpful to pinpoint the issue but unless you can tell me which line is line 35 then I can't help any further. I can count lines but that means nothing as I am not in your environment

Comment: I marked it...it's in the create action in the assignments controller. I marked it like so.... "if @assignment.save  <-------THIS IS LINE 35"

Comment: Post the params passed to this create action please. I think this is related to your model relationships, possibly related to  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_shift`

Comment: The thing is, I can't see the forms that are generating these params so I'm working blind but you might need to look at a fields_for declaration in your form

Comment: Will do.....one moment

Comment: Just to mention again that it is only a deprecation warning and you do not need to solve this right now but it will need to be solved when whatever method in some future rails update you are using is actually removed so you can ignore this warning and move on if needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238926/discussion-between-jamesc-and-thefonso).

Comment: I have my doubts on that `def contact_id=(new_val)` you have in the assignment model, the belongs_to :contact association should take care of setting the Contact object

Comment: Also, this validation `validates_existence_of :contact, :allow_nil => true` makes no sense, you require the existance but you allow nil so you allow non existen contact? and you have an option you can use in the `belongs_to` association for that, by default it's required and you can pass `optional: true` if you don't want to require it. Finally, that validation is not standard, I guess you are using some custom validation or some gem, so that's probably generating that warning.

Comment: @arieljuod it is inherited code that i'm trying to fix. when you say "that validation is not standard"  do you mean only the `validates_existence_of :contact, :allow_nil => true` line or other lines as well?

Comment: `validates_existence_of` is not in the list of rails validations https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html, it seems to come from this gem maybe https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence (super old). Rails 5 and above validates the presence of the associated object in a belongs_to by default, I don't think you need that custom validation